# Find the sub directories sizes of GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have an gcp bucket and wanted to find the sizes of each sub directories with a depth of 2.

For example:

```
GCP bucket is : gs://gcp-bucket/

It has folders under it, in the below way

gs://gcp-bucket/city/a/
gs://gcp-bucket/city/b/
gs://gcp-bucket/city/c/
gs://gcp-bucket/city/d/
```

I wanted to find the size of each of the above folder structures from the Linux server. There are files under those folders but I want to find only the directory size but not the size of files under it.

I tried with gsutil commands but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The option isn't available with `gsutil du ...`. You need to build it.

In fact the reason is simple: directory doesn't exists in Cloud Storage. Only the files that matches the same prefix (the "directory path") are presented in the same "group" or "folder"

Comment: Additional to what Guillaume mentioned, this has been reported in a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/126328548) with Google. A little old but open! They are still evaluating the possibility to add such feature. Use the given link to track Google's progress.